# Create a Woocommerce product widget with category filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to create a WooCommerce products widget like the standard WooCommerce products widget, but with the option to filter on category. I know there is a shortcode for displaying products of a certain category, but I don't like the standard thumbnail view, but like to have a list like in the WooCom products widget.

On Github, I have found the following code which allows to add a WooCom products widget with a filter on product ID:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Woocommerce Custom Widget Product
Description: This plugin help display a list of customs products on your website
Author: Binh Nguyen
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://vietcomic.net/
*/


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

class Bi_Widget_Product extends WP_Widget
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
                'woocommerce_ndbProducts',
                __( 'WP Customs Products', 'ndb' ),
                array('description' => __( 'This plugin help display a list of customs products on your website.', 'ndb' )) 
                );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $ids   = $instance['ids'];
        $arr_id = explode(',',$ids);
        $query_args = array(
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'no_found_rows'  => 1,
            'post__in'       => $arr_id
        ); 

        $r = new WP_Query( $query_args );
        if ( $r->have_posts() ) {

            echo $before_widget;

            if ( $title )
                echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

            echo '<ul class="product_list_widget">';

            while ( $r->have_posts()) {
                $r->the_post();
                global $product;
                 ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?>">
                            <?php echo $product->get_image(); ?>
                            <?php echo $product->get_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php if ( ! empty( $show_rating ) ) echo $product->get_rating_html(); ?>
                        <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                    </li>
                <?php
            }

            echo '</ul>';

            echo $after_widget;
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        echo $content;

    }
    // Widget Backend

    public function form($instance){
        $title = (isset($instance['title'])) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Products', 'ndb' );
        $ids = $instance['ids'];
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title :'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ids'); ?>"><?php _e('IDs :'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ids'); ?>"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'ids' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $ids ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php

    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        $instance['ids'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['ids'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['ids'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }


}



add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
    register_widget( 'Bi_Widget_Product' );
} );
```

Can any of you Wordpress Guru's help me to adapt this so I can filter on category instead of product ID? I'll do an attempt myself, but definitely can use your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for categories them you need to use `get_terms()` query e.g

```
 <?php
    $terms = get_terms( array ( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'description', 'order' => 'ASC' ));

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
       echo $name = $term->name;
    }
?>
```

Solution 2:

```
<?php

//loop the names of the slugs for the country_categories
$terms = get_terms( array ( 'taxonomy' => 'country_categories', 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  //get category slug variables to use in your loop args
  $slug = $term->slug;

  $posts_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'tax_query'         => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array (
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $slug,
      )
    ),
  );

  $posts_query = new WP_Query( $posts_args );
  if( $posts_query->have_posts() ):

    //Each div will have the particular category and its posts. The id and class will also have the slug name
    echo '<div id="' . $slug . '" class="' . $slug . '">
            <h1 class="text-center">' . $term->name . '</h1>
            while( $posts_query->have_posts() ): $posts_query->the_post();
              get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
            endwhile;
  echo '</div>';
  endif;
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @omukiguy. So how should I implement this in the widget to get the products having a particular category? & why does the category method not work? I found it via WP codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query --> see paragraph on Category Parameters.

Comment: To be exact the method above looks for the taxonomy and will give you details of the terms. You can see these if you `var_dump()` However you can get particular products posts in specific categories using this code shared. Character limit wont allow me but check answer above for solution 2. i have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I have generated the widget and you can find the code on my GitHub:
https://github.com/Petasos/WC_ProductsByCategory